# String replacement array of strings in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm confused as to how i can create a new string on the basis of another, replacing some values of the original string,

If i have

```
Array(easy_id, 1_sum(term_invested_points), 1_sum(std_invested_points), 1_sum(std_used_points), 1_sum(term_used_points), 9_sum(term_invested_points))
```

and want to produce

```
Array(easy_id, 1_sum_term_invested_points_, 1_sum_std_invested_points_, 1_sum_std_used_points_, 1_sum_term_used_points_, 9_sum_term_invested_points_)
```

i.e substitute brackets for underscores in my array.

I have tried

```
array.columns.map{ case "" => "("; case x => x }
```

However this just produces the original array, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
val arr = Array(
  "easy_id",
  "1_sum(term_invested_points)",
  "1_sum(std_invested_points)",
  "1_sum(std_used_points)",
  "1_sum(term_used_points)",
  "9_sum(term_invested_points)"
)

arr.map(_.replaceAll("\\(|\\)", "_"))
```

Map inside the array and replace all opening or closing brackets with underscores (brackets need to be escaped with backslashes as they are Regex special characters).